# Create new EditText by click on button (Android)

Tags: android, object, button, android-edittext, element

I want the user can click on that Button to make a new EditText field and can put data and save it if he click on save button.
*** Tell me steps bit by bit because I'm android beginner

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText edittext;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        edittext.setVisibility(8);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        edittext.setVisibility(0);
    }

}
```